# Check if unknown / remote server supports HTTPS

Tags: http, https, server, request, transport

Is there a posibillity to check if a remote server supports https?
Currently im requesting https, if it doesnt work retry http and then display an error if this still does not work.
Is there a feature embedded in HTTP which indicates if https is supported?
By this I dont mean redirect etc. because these must be implemented on the server and arent always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silently falling back to HTTP sounds dangerous. An attacker (i.e. man-in-the-middle) might be able to force you to use the insecure channel by blocking your requests to HTTPS. Thus, I would not recommend this approach in general.

In general, you should let your users decide which protocol to use. If they specify https, you should not silently downgrade but throw an error. If they specify http however, it might be possible to also try https first and silently fall back to http if that fails (since they requested http in the first place).

An a general answer to your request: you can only try https to check if the server supports https. There is an HTTP(s) extension called [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) which allows servers to indicate that all requests to them should always be performed via secure channels only. If you receive such a header in a response for an HTTPS request, you can force https in the future for the host. Note though that you have to ignore such headers receive over insecure HTTP.

In general, you can't trust any information you received over plaintext HTTP to give you any indication about security options (such as support for TLS) of the server since this information could be arbitrarily spoofed by man-in-the-middle attackers. In fact, preventing such undetectable changes is one of the main reasons to use TLS / HTTPS in the first place.